# Apache as oAuth2 consumer (client)

Tags: apache, perl, oauth, reverse-proxy, mod-perl2

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486849/sso-integration-with-apache) the accepted answer "very shortly" suggests the next:

> The SSO module was loaded to Apache webserver which acts as a middle
>   layer between User and tomcat application server.

without giving any exact solution. I didn't found (yet) any oAuth2 client module (mod_auth_oauth2) for apache.

**The question is**: Is possible implement `oAuth2` client for apache, using `mod_perl2` and CPAN module [Net::OAuth2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OAuth2)? Is the module *compatible* with `mod_perl2` or it is pointless to try because will run into problems?

*Background: having several internal web applications what doesn't handles authentication in any way. Now want "publish" them using `apache2.4` configured as a reverse proxy, and therefore need manage authentication directly on the apache level. It is easy to achieve with e.g. [mod_auth_form](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_form.html), but looking for oAuth2 solution what allows login using google,facebook and like oAuth2 Idp.*

And because here isn't yet (at least I didn't found) any `mod_auth_oauth2` module for apache2, looking for solution how to implement it easily - e.g. with `mod_perl2`. Or exists here any reverse proxy what already has implemented oAuth2?

Comment: Could you solve your problem in any way?

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996603/oauth-2-0-authentication-in-http-module) claims that mod_auth_openidc can do it. And there are indeed configuration examples for some oauth2 providers. However it seem that more is needed than vanilla oauth2, as to my question on how to integrate it with github, [I was told](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mod_auth_openidc/d71udWolz5I/9RvJRsqrBQAJ), that it is not supported.